# Graph visualization tool

Tags: graph, visualization

I have an edge list of graph
Nodes are strings, NOT numbers
Also there can be thousands of edges
Can anyone suggest me a graph visualisation tool which accepts graph info in some format -json, CSV etc. And visualizes large graphs. Also it works with graph having strings as nodes

Comment: https://graphviz.org/

Comment: Thanks, I just found even  Gephi is nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/) is open source graph visualization software. Graph visualization is a way of representing structural information as diagrams of abstract graphs and networks. It has important applications in networking, bioinformatics, software engineering, database and web design, machine learning, and in visual interfaces for other technical domains.

[Gephi](https://gephi.org/) is the leading visualization and exploration software for all kinds of graphs and networks. Gephi is open-source and free.

Runs on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Standalone tools:

- [Gephi](https://gephi.org)
- [Cytoscape](https://cytoscape.org/)
- [Tulip](https://tulip.labri.fr/site/)
- [Graphia](https://graphia.app/)

Python packages:

- [pyvis](https://pyvis.readthedocs.io)
- [gravis](https://robert-haas.github.io/gravis-docs/) (Disclaimer: I'm the author)

JavaScript libraries:

- [d3-forces](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/tree/v3.0.0)
- [vis](https://visjs.org/)